# how to set default image in mozilla firefox as a homepage?

Tags: firefox

how to set default image in Mozilla Firefox as a homepage?

Comment: you mean default URL?

Comment: Not default.. I take manually my computer URL suppose '/home/krawler/Desktop/original.jpg'

Answer (score 0):

Go to Mozila Options->General and Set the image URL as Homepage.
[image: Example]